# How to call Owl Slider in Magento2

Tags: javascript, theme, magento-2.0.7, slider

If we want to add **Owl Slider** in Magento 1.X then we follow the below steps.

1. Copy **`owl.carousel.min.js`** and **`owl.carousel.js`** and paste into `skin/frontend/pakage_name/theme_name/js`
2. Copy **`owl.carousel.css`** and paste into `skin/frontend/pakage_name/theme_name/css`
3. Goto `app/design/frontend/pakage_name/theme_name/layout/page.xml` and call js and CSS

And we can use Owl Slider anywhere in Magento 1.X site.

So in Magento 2 how we can call Owl slider and it should be called everywhere in the site so I can use whenever I want.

For this problem, I have referred this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123424/how-to-add-owl-carousel-js-in-custom-file-magento-2) but it's not up to the mark and it's not working.

Right now I have placed Owl slider js in `app/design/frontend/pakage_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/web/js` but it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We also can follow this guide: http://www.boolfly.com/magento-2-slider-with-owl-carousel/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to created one **`requirejs-config.js`** file inside your theme like,

First Add **owlcarousel.js** file inside,

```
app/design/frontend/pakage_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/web/js
```

Add your css inside,

```
app/design/frontend/pakage_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/web/css
```

call css inside your tempalte file using,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Catalog::css/owlcarousel.css')?>">
```

or call css inside a layout file (best practice), depending on your needs :

- **whole site** : `default.xml` for example `app/design/frontend/pakage_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml`
- **Home page** : `cms_index_index.xml`

```
<page ...>
<head>
     <css src="Magento_Catalog::css/owlcarousel.css"/>
</head>
<body>...</body> </page>
```

Now create requirejs-config.js file

```
Magento_Catalog/requirejs-config.js
```

Define your slider,

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
            'owlcarousel': "Magento_Catalog/js/owlcarousel"
        },   
    shim: {
        'owlcarousel': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Now you can use owlcarousel under any phtml file,

```
<div id="owlslider" class="products list items product-items">
   <ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
     <li>4</li>
     <li>5</li>       
  </ul>
</div>
    <script>
    (function  () {
        require(["jquery","owlcarousel"],function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#owlslider").owlCarousel({
                    navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
                    autoPlay: false, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds 
                    items : 5
                });
            });
        });
    })();
    </script>
```

Remove pub/static folder content and run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command.

Comment: but where can I add css? and I need to add css in require.js file??

Comment: you cant add css into require.js file

Comment: I have 3 owl slider files **owl.carousel.css** , **owl.carousel.js**,**owl.carousel.min** and need to add this all files so where can I add and call these all files so I can use in whole magento site wherever I want?

Comment: app/design/frontend/pakage_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/web/css

Comment: i have updatead answer plz check

Comment: if I place owl slider js in magento-catalog then I can use in whole site?

Comment: yes you have to create one requirejs-config.js file same as above in your anotuyer module or theme folder and you can use it.

Comment: thanks for give me solution but if I place in magento-catalog folder then I can use only for this module but I want to use for whole site so it's better to add js and css in root theme folder's web folder.

Comment: its not neccesary to put inside web and you can call each place using above method also you can call any place by giving just path.

Comment: Hi, does this work in Microsoft Edge? Do you have any example? Thanks.

Comment: Hai ,  im  try it above format  i got console error:  `require.js:141 Uncaught Error: Script error for: owl
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)`  Let Me know what mistake im did  @Rakesh

Comment: Please share your question as new post and all the code which you have tried.

Comment: hi, How about ajax-loader.gif and owl.video.play.png, both are used by the css files ?

Answer (score 8):

first you need to put slider at,

**Step1** `themename/themename/Magento_Theme/web/js/owl.carousel.js`

**Step2** Do mapping for the file in  themename/themename/Magento_Theme/requirejs-config.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {


            owlcarouselslider:        'Magento_Theme/js/owl.carousel'

        }
    }
};
```

**Step3** : I have used in bestseller file as below where you need to include slider mapping,
themename/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/bestseller_list.phtml:

```
<script>

    require([
        'jquery',
        'owlcarouselslider'
        ], function () {
            'use strict';
            jQuery.noConflict();
                jQuery("#best-seller-carousel").owlCarousel({
                autoPlay: 3000, //3000 Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
                margin:5,
                items : 5,
                itemsDesktop : [1199,5],
                itemsDesktopSmall : [979,5],
                itemsTablet : [768,5],
                navigation : true,
                pagination : false
          });
    });
</script>
```

**Step4** : For that structure should be as below,

```
<div id="demo">
<div id="best-seller-carousel">
    <div class="item"><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>3</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>4</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>5</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>6</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>7</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>8</h1></div>
</div>
</div>
```

You can also visit more links @ http://cookie-code.net/magento-2/using-requirejs-in-magento-2-implementing-owl-slider/ 
 http://cookie-code.net/magento-2/using-requirejs-in-magento-2-implementing-owl-slider/

Comment: Anytime. Glad to know it worked for you :)

Comment: Are you from ahmedabad?

Comment: I have call owl slider js in requirejs-config.js but my js is not showing in frontend. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @watson Remove pub/static folder content and run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command.

Comment: I do it so many times but didn't work it.

Comment: As you told I palce js file on this path themename/themename/Magento_Theme/web/js/owl.carousel.js
but in requirejs-config.js file you told to add owl js on this path **owlcarouselslider:        'Magento_Theme/js/owl.carousel'** but in first step you have described we have placed js in theme root's web/js folder not in Magento_Theme's js folder so I thing may be it's wrong path. what you think?

Comment: @watson , lets give it a try. Once try to add js in theme  web/js folder and try to access through require(["js/owl.carousel"]  ... means themename/themename/web/js/owl.carousel.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41898/discussion-between-watson-and-rj07).

Comment: send you chat request.

Comment: As you said i have used this in module but it's not working 

magento223/pub/static/version1524899947/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/owlcarouselslider.js net::ERR_ABORTED

Refused to execute script from 'http://192.168.1.174/magento223/pub/static/version1524899947/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/owlcarouselslider.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: owlcarouselslider
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add `owl carousel` in `Magento 2` way, you should follow these steps.

1. Copy `owl.carousel.js` to `app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<theme_name>/web/js/owl-carousel/`.
2. Add your `requirejs` module `app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<theme_name>/web/js/carousel.js`.

   ```
    define([
        'jquery',
        'owlCarousel'
    ], function($) {
        return function(config, element) {
            $(element).owlCarousel(config);
        };
    });
   ```
3. Add `requirejs` config to `app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<theme_name>/requirejs-config.js`.

   ```
    var config = {
        map: {
            '*': {
                'carousel': 'js/carousel',
                'owlCarousel': 'js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel'
            }
        }
    };
   ```

How to use:

- use the `data-mage-init` attribute to insert Owl Carousel in a certain element:

  ```
   <div class="owl-carousel" data-mage-init='{"carousel":{"option": value}}'>
       <div class="item">Item 1</div>
       ...
       <div class="item">Item n</div>
   </div>
  ```
- use with `<script type="text/x-magento-init" />`:

  ```
   <div id="owl-carousel" class="owl-carousel">
       <div class="item">Item 1</div>
       ...
       <div class="item">Item n</div>
   </div>

   <script type="text/x-magento-init">
   {
       "#owl-carousel": {
           "carousel": {"option": value}
       }
   }
   </script>
  ```

Comment: can we use without data-mage-init?

Comment: This is not a relevant question. This example shows how to use `Owl Carousel` in `Magento` way approach with `data-mage-init` or `text/x-magento-init`

Answer (score 1):

The other 2 answers are excellent, and I have copied elements of both, but I was occasionally finding issues with error messages "$ is not a function" and "Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined". Also I wanted a method centred on the content pages.

So this combined method might help somebody

1. Copy owl.carousel.js into  app/design/frontend/*vendorname*/*themename*/Magento_Theme/web/js

(create directory if not already there)

2. The other css solution could work just as well, or you could copy owl.carousel.css and owl.theme.default.css into the .Less file for the theme, and adjust styling to your preferences.
3. Copy the following code into app/design/frontend/*vendorname*/*themename*/Magento_Theme/require-config.js

(create file / directory if necessary, this code appears to solve the "cannot read property of FN" issue.)

```
var config = {
paths: {            
        'owlcarousel': "Magento_Theme/js/owl.carousel"
    },   
shim: {
    'owlcarousel': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
};
```

4. In the page content place the following code to define the carousel images

   ```
   <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
     <div><img src="{blah blah}"/></div>
     <div><img src="{blah blah}"/></div>
     <div><img src="{blah blah}"/></div>
     <div><img src="{blah blah}"/></div>
   </div>
   ```
5. After the above code, add the following code for the carousel (this appears to solve the "$ is not a function" error )

   ```
   <script>
       require([
           'jquery',
           'owlcarousel'
           ], function () {
               'use strict';
               jQuery.noConflict();
                   jQuery(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                       nav: true, // Show next and prev buttons
                       navText:["<",">"], //show prev next
                       loop: true,
                       autoplay: true, //Set AutoPlay  
                       autoplayHoverPause: true, //stop when mouse on carousel
                       items : 1
             });
       });
   </script>
   ```
6. Deploy the static content, e.g. php magento setup:static-content:deploy (note there are various methods for doing this which involve the manual clearing of cache folders and a php magento cache:clean command).
7. Check it out on the website

Comment: i tried but slider is not coming. although when i inspect element owl class does get added to the div

Answer (score 0):

I'm new at magento 2, and had same challenge.. after hours and hours of searching, what worked for me was..

1 - Download owl-carousel2 js source code to
app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/web/js/owl-carousel/owlcarousel.js

2 - Add jquery 3.x source code at (because owl-carousel2 compability)
app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/web/js/jquery-custom.js

3 - Add in requirejs-config.js at
app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/requirejs-config.js

```
map: {
    "*": {
        "<themeName>/jquery": "js/jquery-custom",
        owlcarousel: "js/owl-carousel/owlcarousel",
        main_custom: "js/main-custom.js",
    },
    shim: {
        owlcarousel: {
            deps: "<themeName>/jquery",
        },
    },
},
```

4 - Then in my main-custom.js at app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/web/js/main-custom.js (or anywhere else you want to use)

require(["jquery", "beleaf/jquery", "owlcarousel"], function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".main-banner.owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
nav: true,
navText: [
"<",
">",
],
autoplay: true,
autoplayHoverPause: true,
items: 1,
});
});
});

Obs.: If any files of those exists in your project, then just create them.

Hope it helps buddys.

Answer (score -1):

```
define([
    "jquery",
], function ($) {
    !function(a,b,c,d){function e(b,c)................................(window.Zepto||window.jQuery,window,document)
});
```

You should add `owl.carousel.min.js` on magento2