# Magento2: owl carousel issue

Tags: magento-2.1

after created symlinks my owl carousel not working when i open console it shows

```
    owl.carousel.js:1794Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined(anonymous function) @ owl.carousel.js:1794(anonymous function) @ owl.carousel.js:1808
    custom.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) @ custom.js:1
    owl.carousel.js:1794 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined(anonymous function) @ owl.carousel.js:1794(anonymous function) @ owl.carousel.js:1808
     jquery-migrate.js:21 JQMIGRATE: Logging is active
   (index):914 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).owlCarousel is not a       function(anonymous function) @ (index):914context.execCb @ require.js:1650Module.check @ require.js:866(anonymous function) @ require.js:1113(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ require.js:1156each @ require.js:57Module.emit @ require.js:1155Module.check @ require.js:917Module.enable @ require.js:1143Module.init @ require.js:774callGetModule @ require.js:1170context.completeLoad @ require.js:1564context.onScriptLoad @ require.js:1671
```

Comment: Do you get any solution for this ? cause i am having same issue.

Comment: Still having issue with Magento2.3 to include carousel library. Having same error.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156997)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Put your js inside require statement.

```
require(['jquery'], function($){
//your js code here
 });
```

Or else you can include your js properly using requireJs.

You can also refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/123733/51548

Answer (score -1):

```
define([
    "jquery",
], function ($) {
    !function(a,b,c,d)....................window.Zepto||window.jQuery,window,document)
});
```

fixed by define owl.carousel.min.js like this.