# How to build custom theme with page and static blocks in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, theme, custom-theme

I am trying to create custom theme with inbuilt Cms pages and Blocks? For example once the theme files moved and installed can able to see all the blocks and pages are created in magento.

I followed below link 
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-custom-theme-magento-2-part-1/

Which is for overriding luma theme but not able to Preview the theme with content.

How can we create theme with full package along with slider, Blocks and widgets like the Paid themes?
For example in this Url: https://www.hiddentechies.com/bizkick-responsive-theme-magento-2.html

Once we buy we will get full package with all pages,blocks and widgets. How we can create like this exactly from scratch? Please anyone suggest with links or with step by step Guide,

All i need is i am going to create two custom themes, so page,and blocks are different for each theme.

So whenever a,theme is applied in admin, those page content should show in frontend.. Thanks

Comment: You need to create the sliders/blocks yourself, you can use sample data included [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data) but it doesn't contain sliders.

Comment: Check links, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-create-custom-theme-in-magento-2/

Comment: Yes, Like this i already created new theme, i am looking for how to create themes like the paid one, There we will get all blocks and pages all installed once the theme is applied, but the above link you provided that creates the theme, for that we need to add static blocks for that theme mannually.

Answer (score 2):

This is too broad question but i tried sum up for you. You can create the basic theme with currently provided link. But for creating theme data import you need to create module's for  importing data. Like if follow this example for creating the cms block for run time.

Create [installer Script](https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/CmsSampleData/Setup/Installer.php)

Create [csv data](https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/CmsSampleData/fixtures/blocks/categories_static_blocks.csv)

Save with [model](https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/CmsSampleData/Model/Block.php)

Now taking [example](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-create-install-schema/)

```
<?php

namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface {
    private $blockFactory;

    public function __construct(
\Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory
 )
    {

    $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
    }  
    public function install( SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context ) {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

       $testBlock = [
         'title' => 'Test block title',
         'identifier' => 'test-block',
         'stores' => [0],
         'is_active' => 1,
         ];
        $this->blockFactory->create()->setData($testBlock)->save();

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide simple steps just to show only slider block for now? rest i will do it myself

Comment: @jafar i added the example too.

Comment: Thanks for posting it. How it is relate to custom theme? say for example My custom theme is <Demo>/<CustomDemo>. with same name do i need to create custom module with this?. Can you please elaborate it with some steps?

Comment: block identifier is unique `test-block`. you theme have you own identifier that are used in theme.

Comment: Please explain it from scratch? yes that is unique id, but my question is different,  How can i start building theme can you please explain with directory structure and files?

Comment: @jafar follow this https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-create-simple-theme/

Comment: @Quisar, i have created sample theme already, please read my question. I am asking i need a simple slider carousel or any other slider block to be installed on activating our theme. Please help in code how this can be achieved?

Comment: @jafar i think it is not matching the question title .How to build custom theme in Magento2. follow https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123727/how-to-call-owl-slider-in-magento2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80275/discussion-between-jafar-and-qaisar-satti).