# How to implement owl carousel in custom module?

Tags: magento2, owl-carousel

I have tried to implement owl carousel slider in custom module followed [How to call Owl Slider in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123727/how-to-call-owl-slider-in-magento2)

my phtml file

```
<div class="products list items product-items owlslider">
   <ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
     <li>4</li>
     <li>5</li>       
  </ul>
</div>
    <script>
    (function  () {
        require(["jquery","owlcarousel"],function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".owlslider").owlCarousel({
                    navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
                    autoPlay: false, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds 
                    items : 5
                });
            });
        });
    })();
    </script>
```

app/code/vendor/modulename/view/frontend/web/js/require-config.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
            'owlcarousel': "web/js/owlcarousel"
        },   
    shim: {
        'owlcarousel': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

I am getting script error Uncaught Error: Script error for: owlcarousel

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing inline script, it is better to do it using js component as follows:

Code in **phtml** file

```
<div class="products list items product-items">
   <ul id="owlslider">
     <li><img src="some image" /></li>
     <li><img src="some image" /></li>
     <li><img src="some image" /></li>      
  </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#owlslider": {
            "carousel": {
                    "navigation" : true,
                    "center": true,
                    "margin":10,
                    "responsiveClass":true,
                    "responsive":{
                        "0":{
                            "items":1,
                            "nav":true
                        },
                        "600":{
                            "items":2,
                            "nav":true
                        },
                        "1000":{
                            "items":3,
                            "nav":true
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Code in **requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'carousel': 'js/carousel',
            'owlCarousel': 'js/owl.carousel.min'
        }
    }
};
```

Then, I have placed `carousel.js` and `owl.carousel.min.js` in `web/js` in my module.

code in **carousel.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'owlCarousel'
], function($) {
    return function(config, element) {
        $(element).owlCarousel(config);
    };
});
```

You can modify the code and carousel configuration according to your requirement.

Comment: not work for me magento 2.3

Comment: @Anshu "margin":10 parameter not working here

Comment: @matinict did you find any solution?

Comment: @surbhiagr i implemented https://codepen.io/vilcu/pen/ZQwdGQ you may try if face problem inform me

Comment: @matinict I have tried adding all these code in a phtml file but the images doesnt slide and slider is not coming. Can you please help