# Add custom slider for banners

Tags: magento2, banner-slider, owl-carousel

I have two banners that are showing on frontend. I want to show them in a slider. Please suggest something.

Comment: you can use owl carousel library, check this link of installation :
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html

Comment: and you can check its working demo as well here https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html

Comment: please specify for particular help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following extensions:

https://www.weltpixel.com/owl-carousel-and-slider.html

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-banner-slider-extension/

Or you can use owl.carousel.js and it's CSS directly by including it in your theme.

Please follow the link:

[How to call Owl Slider in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123727/how-to-call-owl-slider-in-magento2)

Comment: I dont want to use any extension. I have to make it by own.Currently i can add and show banner from backend to frontend. Now i want those banners in slider. Can you please elaborate about the owl carousal method

Comment: I updated answer.

Comment: i have checked this link but slider doesnt appear

Answer (score 0):

Create 
**Step1**

> app/design/frontend/Your/theme/web/js/owl/owl.carousel.js

Copy the content from here 
https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/blob/develop/src/js/owl.carousel.js

**Step2**

> app/design/frontend/Your/theme/web/js/slider.js

(update Your/theme with your path directory name)

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'js/owl/owl.carousel'
], function ($) {
    return function(config, element) {
        $(function () {
            $(element).owlCarousel({
                items: config.slidesToShow,
                slideBy: config.slideBy,
                loop: config.loop,
                dots: config.dots,
                nav: config.nav,
                autoplay: config.autoplay,
                autoplayTimeout: config.autoplayTimeout,
                autoplayHoverPause: true,
                rewind: config.rewind,
                responsive: config.responsive                
            })
        });
    };
});
```

**Step 3**
Use the slider in cms blocks

```
    <div class="owl-carousel"
        data-mage-init='{"js/slider":{
                    "slidesToShow": 5,
                    "slideBy": 5,
                    "rewind": "true"
                    }}' >
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a phtml file from which banners are coming. This is not working

Comment: do you find error or something in your browser console?

Comment: @Ylgen Guxholli It is not working

Comment: @RendyEkoPrastiyo no error is coming in console