# How Can I add Any jQuery Plugin in Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I am trying to add owl Carousel js file in **`app/design/frontend/My/theme/web/js/carousel.min.js`**
but I am unable to add it to my site header.

Comment: you need to add the js file in layout header for that page or use the require-config stuff.

Comment: Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123727/how-to-call-owl-slider-in-magento2?answertab=oldest#tab-top